# Generating data using grf and plotting its variogram- Result intrepretation

Tags: r, spatial

I have a question about the semivariogram plot:

Suppose I generated 50 data points from Gaussian random field (using grf function in R), and assumed that we have exponential covariance model with $\sigma^2 = 1$ and $\phi=0.5$, and $\phi$ here represents the range which can be defind as "The distance in which the difference of the variogram from the sill becomes negligible".

So when we plot the semivariogram for the generated data, we would assume that the range is going to be around 0.5, but it is not!

Here is code I'm using. Can someone explain what's going on, or I'm missing something? Thanks!

```
![grd <- expand.grid(seq(0, 1, l=5), seq(0, 1, l=5))
sdata <- grf(50, grid="reg", cov.pars=c(1, 0.5), cov.model="exponential")
plot(sdata)][1]
```

Comment: 50 points is a small sample to use: you cannot expect it to estimate the variogram reliably.  What results do you get with, say, 300 sample points?  What happens when you repeat your simulation?